# Is it possible to filter array values by multiple values by using underscore?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have the following array of values:

```
[
   {
     id: 1,
     field: 'map'
   },
   {
     id: 2,
     field: 'dog'
   },
   {
     id: 3,
     field: 'map'
   }
]
```

I need to find out elements with field equals `dog` and `map`.  I know I could use the `_.filter` method and pass an iterator function, but what I want to know is **whether or not there's a better solution to this issue where I could pass search field and possible values**.  Could someone provide a better way of doing so?

**EDIT:**:

I could use the  following approach:

```
_.where(array, {field: 'dog'})
```

But here I may check only one clause

Answer (score 21):

```
_.filter(data, function(item){ return item.field === 'map' || item.field === 'dog'; })
```

If you want to create a function which accepts `field` and `values` it can look like this:

```
function filter(data, field, values) {
    _.filter(data, function(item){ return _.contains(values, item[field]); })
}
```

Comment: The question wasn't exactly clear but the question he's actually asking is how to make it more customizable/generic: "I know I may to use _.filter method and pass iterator function but **is there better solution where I could pass search field and possible values**?"

Answer (score 8):

Just pass your filter criteria as the third parameter of [`_.filter(list, predicate, [context])`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) which is then set as the `context` (`this`) of the iterator:

```js
var data = [
  { id: 1, field: 'map'   },
  { id: 2, field: 'dog'   },
  { id: 3, field: 'blubb' }
];

var filtered = _.filter(
  data,
  function(i) { return this.values.indexOf(i.field) > -1; },
  { "values": ["map", "dog"] } /* "context" with values to look for */
);

console.log(filtered);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```